# Python regex matching c++ typedef'd enums

Tags: python, regex, parsing, match, findall

I'd like some help to build a regex matching the following string format:

```
typedef enum x
{
    ...
} z;
```

Where I want to get the value of x and z even tho they are not specified.

Thanks!

Comment: If they're not specified, how would you get the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
str_typedef = """typedef enum x
{
    ...
} z;"""
pattern = 'typedef\s+enum\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*{[^{}]*}\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*;'
rs = re.findall(pattern, str_typedef)
for r in rs:
    enum_type_name = r.group(1)
    enum_name = r.group(2)
    # do operations with results here, or store to an array 
    # of dictionaries for use later.
```

Here, `enum_type_name` would end up being "x" or whichever other name is in place of x, and `enum_name` would end up being "z" or whichever other name is in place of z.

A quick summary of the expression:

Each `\s+` is one or more space or new line, and each `\s*` is the same, but making the white space optional.

Each `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)` will catch and store a group of one or more alpha-numeric characters for a c++ variable/class/enum name.

`{[^{}]*}` means a `{` followed by any number of characters that aren't `{` or `}`, and then a `}`.